# Throwing Custom Exception and Display Error Message from Custom AuthenticationProvider

Tags: grails, spring-security

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412591/hooking-into-pre-authentication-with-spring-security-core).

I have a custom AuthenticationProvider that extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.  In the additionalAuthenticationChecks I am doing some custom auth work and part of this process is to display some messages to the user on the login screen.  Currently, for testing, I created a UserNotActivatedException:

```
class UserNotActivatedException extends AuthenticationException {

  public UserNotActivatedException(String message, Throwable t) {
    super(message, t)
  }

  public UserNotActivatedException(String message) {
    super(message)
  }

  public UserNotActivatedException(String message, Object extraInformation) {
    super(message, extraInformation)
  }

}
```

And in the additionalAuthenticationChecks I am just immediately throwing it for testing.  Now, I need to know what I need to do to get my own fail message to show up on the login screen.  In the spring-security-core default config, we can override the following:

```
errors.login.disabled = "Sorry, your account is disabled."
errors.login.expired = "Sorry, your account has expired."
errors.login.passwordExpired = "Sorry, your password has expired."
errors.login.locked = "Sorry, your account is locked."
errors.login.fail = "Sorry, we were not able to find a user with that username and password."
```

But I don't see how I can add my own additional messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like those messages just get used by the `authfail` action of the `LoginController` that gets generated into `grails-app/controllers`. Here's the code from the template (in the plugin):

```
/**
 * Callback after a failed login. Redirects to the auth page with a warning message.
 */
def authfail = {

    def username = session[UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY]
    String msg = ''
    def exception = session[WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION]
    if (exception) {
        if (exception instanceof AccountExpiredException) {
            msg = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.errors.login.expired
        }
        else if (exception instanceof CredentialsExpiredException) {
            msg = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.errors.login.passwordExpired
        }
        else if (exception instanceof DisabledException) {
            msg = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.errors.login.disabled
        }
        else if (exception instanceof LockedException) {
            msg = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.errors.login.locked
        }
        else {
            msg = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.errors.login.fail
        }
    }

    if (springSecurityService.isAjax(request)) {
        render([error: msg] as JSON)
    }
    else {
        flash.message = msg
        redirect action: auth, params: params
    }
}
```

*(from ~/.grails/1.3.7/projects/project-name/plugins/spring-security-core-1.1.2/src/templates/LoginController.groovy.template)*

You can probably just add your UserNotActivatedException type to the conditions there.

Comment: Ahh, Good catch.  I'll go give that a shot and see what happens.

Comment: You the man!  Worked.  I feel a blog article coming on after all this work today. :o)

Comment: Glad it worked :) - I've not changed the authfail action myself, but it seemed pretty straightforward. I've been doing a handful of custom AuthenticationProvider stuff myself as well lately; this may come in handy for my own use down the road, I suppose.