# Tivoli Access Manager with Grails spring security

Tags: grails, spring-security, tivoli

Does anyone over here has experience integrating TAM with Grails spring security for single sign on. If so can you help me get a quick start or point to any tutorials.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to use Spring Security's pre authentication feature and examine the header sent from TAM. To do so you would write your own authentication provider which is really simple and just looks for the header. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412591/hooking-into-pre-authentication-with-spring-security-core) for some more information